# Is it necessary to learn C# before starting to work on Windows Phone 8.1 development?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

NB: This question may appear too broad or off-topic.

I have no knowledge about C# or about Windows Phone 8.1 development.

I have basic knowledge of C++ & have worked in PHP.

From tomorrow I have to work on WP 8.1. Since there is no time to learn C#, I am asking you whether it is necessary to learn C# first before starting to work on WP 8.1??

If, which topics should I gave more priority?? Any topics that I can skip.

C# fundamentals can be found [here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Fundamentals-for-Absolute-Beginners).

For WP 8.1, I am trying to follow this [course](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/01).

Comment: With all respect: Since there is no time, why do bother to ask? Anyway a short answer: `yes, most likely`

Comment: offhand i'd say: wait one day and tell us tomorrow. But yes, you probably need to learn c#.

Comment: A basic knowledge of C++ and PHP will help (depending on how basic it is), but jumping into Windows Phone development (which relies heavily on XAML for the presentation) will be a steep learning curve.  You would be better served to learn C# fundamentals first.

Comment: Knowing C# is the last of your problems. Knowing the NET Framework Library is another thing.

Comment: And what if you get to already existing project and get to work on logic - straight to c# programming

Comment: Yes. I have to be a part of an already existing project. That's what concerns me. @Reniuz

Comment: I asked because I wanted to know how hard I have to work. @N55PEC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that knowledge of C# is no prerequisite if you know other similar languages.

But to write good and maintainable good you **should** know the language features and idioms.

If you want to get started as quickly as possible, skim the chapters of your C# books so you get an idea of what is possible. When you need to write code that handles a specific part of the language, open your books to the chapters that handle it.

Try to look up / learn what is needed when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you say that there is now time, so try to get an idea about the .net itself and some c# hints for c++ programmers like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyaad03b(v=vs.90).aspx
And yes you need to know about c# to develop on windows phone. so get a c# book and read in it a little everyday and you will get better step by step.
Also one important point is the visual studio itself, you need to know how to deal with.